# webkit.framework missing for arhicteture xxx after adding Fabric to project?

Tags: ios, crashlytics, crashlytics-beta

I am using Xcode 5.1 and I have project that previously worked well with crashlytics beta framework I recently upgraded my account to Fabric and tried to add support for that in my project (followed all steps) but I get this weird error when I try to build it.

```
ld: framework not found WebKit for architecture arm64
```

Did anyone else experience this issue ? Is there solution for this ?

PS:

I reverted to old crashlytics.framework lib and I am able to build application but I can't add new versions to crashlytics.

Comment: I have the same issue, it seems we can only compile project using Crashlitics with XCode 6